# Why is the header for HTTP Authentication called "Authorization" and not "Authentication"

Tags: http, authentication, authorization, rfc

As I understand, to "Authenticate" means to prove you are who you claim to be. To be "Authorized" means that you have permission to do the operation you are attempting.

Why then, in the [RFC for HTTP authentication](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt), do you authenticate (prove you are who you say you are) via a header called 'Authorization'? You are not proving that you are allowed to do a certain operation.

> The "basic" authentication scheme is based on the model that the
>      client must authenticate itself with a user-ID and a password for
>      each realm...
>
> ...If the user agent wishes to send the userid "Aladdin" and password
>      "open sesame", it would use the following header field:
>
> > ```
> > Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
> > ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

a) The actual RFC is 7235, not 2617.

b) I assume it's a historic mistake. That's the best answer I have (note that I'm one of the authors of the newer RFC)

Comment: Thank you!

On a similar vein, do you think the response 401 "Unauthorized" would make more sense as 401 "Unauthenticated"? At least, in this context.